Convert an Excel file into an AML file with EPPlus
Using EPPlus, I want to Convert an Excel Sheet with Information about diffrent devices into an AML file so I can export it in to TIA V18. My Excel file has all Information that is needet for a device configuration (EAAddress, IP-Address, Profinet Name etc.). Problem is I cant get an AML File that TIA is accepting.
I tried a code but it wont lode into TIA. This massage is coming up: The AML file 'DeviceConfiguration.aml' selected for import is invalid. The RefRoleClassPath attribute was not declared

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example
